# Delete posts --- how can we appeal?

Tags: support, moderation, deleted-answers

My answers to a post were deleted as "not answering the question." I admit they didn't answer the direct halachic question (I'm not qualified!) specifically, but did provide an answer/solution. It was deleted. I don't really agree with the reasoning, but don't know how to discuss the issue. Suggestions?

Comment: Meta is the place to bring it up for community discussion.  Thank you for doing so.  If you could link to the question it will be easier to address.  People with enough reputation will still be able to see the deleted answers.  Stack Exchange is designed with these kinds of checks and balances.

Comment: Hi Monica, I think I'm having trouble figuring out what's pertinent, or at least how much value I can add. I think I'll just read for a while. Could I earn a badge for "Earnest Reader"? ;-)

Answer (score 3):

You can appeal either by:

- bringing it up with the community here on Meta.
- discussing it with the moderators either by flagging and explaining clearly your reasoning or asking (via flag or in chat) for a private chat room with them.

Feel free to double check others' decisions; deletions and closures have been reverted in the past.